# Xamarin XLabs Geolocator not working on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-emulator, xlabs

I have access fine and coarse location checked in the manifest file and first time the application runs on the android emulator (Android_Accelerated_x86 (Android 7.1 - API 25)) it logs the latitude. But if I deploy the app for the second time, third time and so on it runs endlessly even though the timeout is 10000 ms (no Exception thrown). If I close and open the emulator and deploy the app again it works again and so on. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
public static class NetworkingTools
{
    private static IGeolocator locator = Resolver.Resolve<IGeolocator>();

    static NetworkingTools()
    {
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
        locator.StartListening(2000, 0, true);
        GetPosition();
    }

    public async static void GetPosition()
    {
        var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(10000);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(position.Latitude);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the remark they have on their [GitHub](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) page:

> NOTICE: This project is no longer maintained. It may not work with newer versions of Xamarin.Forms.

I think it is unwise to integrate this into your project if you have the choice. Instead have a look at the [Geolocator Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) by James Montemagno.

Comment: I tried it, but it had the same problem. Right now I'm using Google Play Services - Location. At the core of the android access location it will subscribe to location changed even to get the current location. The first time the app is run it changes from null to mock position. After that the position is stored, so it doesn't change and if you try to get it, it will run endlessly. Only Google lets you access the last known position that is stored between sessions directly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but apparently that's the way the emulators work. There is no problem with the code, you have to open the EMULATOR Settings, go to Location and Click SEND.

More details here:

[Getting Location on Android Emulator more then once](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/issues/102)